# MVC form capture problems

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can't work this one out, half works half doesn't and I can't see why:

have a form I am entering details into and checked for typos and things like that but only part of the data seems to be captured and pushed back to the controller.

So first it is based on this model:

```
    public class First
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string NiNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Al  { get; set; }
    public decimal RolledOver { get; set; }
    public int HomePhone { get; set; }
    public int MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string AdName { get; set; }
    public int InproNo { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsContractor { get; set; }
    public int IsContractorInt { get; set; }
    public bool IsPartTime { get; set; }
    public int IsPartTimeInt { get; set; }
}
```

this session variable looks at the model:

```
    public class MySessionValues
    {
        public First Employee ;
        public Second Department;
        public Fourth Checked;

        // other steps here ...
    }
}
```

This is a section where i have an issue:

The drop down box works but the title is coming back empty when i try to display it

```
div class="div-dd-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) </div>
                <div class="div-dropdown-menu" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NameTitle, "Please select a title", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="textbox", id = "txtTitle" } })</div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  </div>
```

The surname works but the DateOfBirth is coming back empty

```
    <div style="display: table-row;">                  
        <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname) </div>
        <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtSurname" } }) </div>
        <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  </div>   
        <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth) </div>
        <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtDateOfBirth" } }) </div>
        <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  </div>                      
    </div>
```

both always return false/0 even when ticked:

```
<div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsContractor) </div>
                <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell">  <div>IsContractor @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsContractor, new { id = "txtIsContractor", value = 1 })</div> </div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsContractor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  </div>                
                <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsPartTime) </div>
                <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell">  <div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsPartTime, new { id = "txtIsPartTime", value = 1 })</div> </div>
                <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsPartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  </div>
```

in the partial view i have this to capture the values:

```
<script>
    var urlAction = "@Url.Content("~/Treeview/_NewEmpDetails")";
    function AjaxGoodRedirect(urlAction) {
        console.log(urlAction);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlAction,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Title: $("#txtTitle").val()
                , Initials: $("#txtInitials").val()                
                , Forename: $("#txtForename").val()
                , MiddleName: $('#txtMiddleName').val()
                , Surname: $("#txtSurname").val()
                , DateOfBirth: $("txtDateOfBirth").val()
                , Gender: $("txtGender").val()
                , Nationality: $("txtNationality").val()
                , NiNumber: $("txtNiNumber").val()
                , Al: $("txtAl").val()
                , RolledOver: $("txtRolledOver").val()
                , HomePhone: $("txtHomePhone").val()
                , MobilePhone: $("txtMobilePhone").val()
                , Email: $("txtEmail").val()
                , AdName: $("txtAdName").val()
                , InproNo: $("txtInproNo").val()
                , StartDate: $("txtStartDate").val()
                , IsContractorInt: $("txtIsContractor").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
                , IsPartTimeInt: $("txtIsPartTime").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0
            }),
            datatype: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (returndata) {
                if (returndata.ok)
                    $("#detailView").load(returndata.newurl);
                else
                    window.alert(returndata.message);

            }
        }
        );
    }
</script>
```

the controller section:

```
 public ActionResult _NewEmpDetails()
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NameTitle = new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())
            {
                ViewBag.NameTitle = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpTitle").ToList());

            }

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender = new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (EIPInternalEntities ctx = new EIPInternalEntities())
            {
                ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.uspGetLkUpGender").ToList());

            }

            return View();
        }   

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _NewEmpDetails(NewEmp.First model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var sessionValues = new MySessionValues();
                sessionValues.Employee = model;
                Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;

            }
            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = ("/Treeview/_NewEmpSecond") }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }





        public ActionResult _NewEmpSecond()
        {
            var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;
            ViewBag.NameTitle = sessionValues.Employee.Title;
            ViewBag.Initials = sessionValues.Employee.Initials;
            ViewBag.Forename = sessionValues.Employee.Forename;
            ViewBag.MiddleName = sessionValues.Employee.MiddleName;
            ViewBag.DateOfBirth = sessionValues.Employee.DateOfBirth;
            ViewBag.Surname = sessionValues.Employee.Surname;            
            ViewBag.Gender = sessionValues.Employee.Gender;
            ViewBag.Nationality = sessionValues.Employee.Nationality;
            ViewBag.NiNumber = sessionValues.Employee.NiNumber;
            ViewBag.Al = sessionValues.Employee.Al;
            ViewBag.RolledOver = sessionValues.Employee.RolledOver;
            ViewBag.HomePhone = sessionValues.Employee.HomePhone;
            ViewBag.MobilePhone = sessionValues.Employee.MobilePhone;
            ViewBag.Email = sessionValues.Employee.Email;
            ViewBag.AdName = sessionValues.Employee.AdName;
            ViewBag.InproNo = sessionValues.Employee.InproNo;
            ViewBag.StartDate = sessionValues.Employee.StartDate;
            ViewBag.IsContractor = sessionValues.Employee.IsContractor;
            ViewBag.IsContractorInt = sessionValues.Employee.IsContractorInt;
            ViewBag.IsPartTime = sessionValues.Employee.IsPartTime;
            ViewBag.IsPartTimeInt = sessionValues.Employee.IsPartTimeInt;



            return PartialView();
        }
```

and displaying the result foe debugging in _NewEMpSecond

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div> Value check for Title: @ViewBag.NameTitle </div>
    <div> Value check for Initials: @ViewBag.Initials </div>
    <div> Value check for DateOfBirth: @ViewBag.DateOfBirth </div>
    <div> Value check for Forename: @ViewBag.Forename </div>
    <div> Value check for MiddleName: @ViewBag.MiddleName </div>
    <div> Value check for Surname: @ViewBag.Surname </div>    
    <div> Value check for Gender: @ViewBag.Gender </div>
    <div> Value check for Nationality: @ViewBag.Nationality </div>
    <div> Value check for NiNumber: @ViewBag.NiNumber </div>
    <div> Value check for Al: @ViewBag.Al </div>
    <div> Value check for RolledOver: @ViewBag.RolledOver </div>
    <div> Value check for HomePhone: @ViewBag.HomePhone </div>
    <div> Value check for MobilePhone: @ViewBag.MobilePhone </div>
    <div> Value check for Email: @ViewBag.Email </div>
    <div> Value check for AdName: @ViewBag.AdName </div>
    <div> Value check for InproNo: @ViewBag.InproNo </div>
    <div> Value check for StartDate: @ViewBag.StartDate </div>
    <div> Value check for IsContractor: @ViewBag.IsContractor </div>
    <div> Value check for IsContractorInt: @ViewBag.IsContractorInt </div>
    <div> Value check for IsPartTime: @ViewBag.IsPartTime </div>
    <div> Value check for IsPartTimeInt: @ViewBag.IsPartTimeInt </div>
```

any obvious reason what I have overlooked or messed up on?

Comment: You have forgotten the `#` in `DateOfBirth: $("txtDateOfBirth").val()` when making the ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selectors need to have a # if you lookup by id.

Comment: It's always something small and obvious! thanks.

Any idea why the drop down box for title isn't being captured though?

Comment: There is no specified html id in your code, you need to set it, otherwise the default generated takes over.

Comment: This is the line, doesn't it set the selected value to be txtTitle?

 <div class="div-dropdown-menu" , style="display: table-cell">  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NameTitle, "Please select a title", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="textbox", id = "txtTitle" } })</div>

Comment: that sets the id of the drop down to "txtTitle". the value will be set from `model.Title`

Comment: Since adding a # the Al and RolledOver ones I get the below error:

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Line 126:            var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;
Line 127:            //ViewBag.NameTitle = sessionValues.Employee.Title;
Line 128:            ViewBag.Initials = sessionValues.Employee.Initials;

Comment: The only difference with these is they are decimal, can you see why they cause the missing reference error for another ViewBag?

Answer (score 0):

Try first to check the data you are posting. Also you don't need to enumerate the values there, just use `$(form).serializeArray()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) which will provide the JSON array of your form fields.